# IMPORT EN MASSE D'UN FICHIER DANS LA BASE

Tags: contacts

Bonjour,

Je souhaiterai importer un fichier de contacts dans la base mais je ne sais pas comment procéder. Pouvez-vous m'aider à ce sujet ?

Vous en remerciant par avance et restant à votre disposition, je vous souhaite une bonne fin de journée.

Bien cordialement.

Elodie PAJOT
Assistante administrative
3 Rue de la lionne – 45000 ORLEANS
Tél. 02 38 62 46 97 – www.fne.asso.fr

Comment: Does this link help? https://docs.civicrm.org/user/fr/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/

Comment: Bonjour ! Merci ! je vais essayer mais ça a l'air complet ! Ca devrait aller ! Bonne journée.